# Rotate my camera (python scripts ) from my web page

Tags: php, python

So all I want is to rotate my webcam using a servo moteur, so when I click one of the three buttons (which the program will execute a python script) I get no result! Please any help?

The Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['rotateright'])) {
shell_exec("python Rotateright.py"); 
}
elseif (isset($_POST['rotatedefault'])) {
shell_exec("python defaultpositon.py");
}
elseif (isset($_POST['rotateleft'])) {
shell_exec("python Rotateright.py");
}
?>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="camerasurveillance.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container1">
<a href="../pageaccueil.html"><img class="home" src="home.png"/></a>
        </div>
<div class="container">
<br><br><br>
<!--<img class="live" src="http://192.168.1.8:8082/?action=stream" 
width="500" height="350" alt="Live Feed" title="Raspberry pi" />-->
    <br>
     <form method="POST"> 
     <input class="Rotater" type="submit" name="rotateright" value="Rotation 
Ã  droite">
     <input class="default" type="submit" name="rotatedefault" 
value="Position initiale">
     <button class="Rotatel" name="rotateleft">Rotation Ã  gauche</button>
     </from>
    </div>   
              </div>
```

Comment: `I get no result` doesnt help us. the code seems to run either of `Rotateright.py, defaultpositon.py or Rotateright.py`. firstly please debug and know if these files are being executed or not. If not then its a php error. if its running then it might be a python code error.

Comment: no i test all those scripts and they perfectly works , when i click on the button the page refreshed and there is no action !

Comment: Ok, then please update your php file as it is incomplete.